# config.filter_params is not filtering name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My **filter_params_logging.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password,:name]
```

`:name` was added by me.

But in the rails console I am still able to see the name values. It is not showing `FILTERED` as expected. What might be the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always be able to see the values in the console.  Filtering params stops the values from being seen in the logs.  So in a browser, if you go edit a `Profile` model that has the attributes: name, favorite_color, likes_disco.  Then you should see the following PATCH statement in your log:

```
Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"X+UfN+Bu0mikbNPLO
av5UwW3pFj0gkJhKs1y7lsPVg9CzSi1QEmHzGDVkm8Bc5BDtJFv+gQ==", "profile"=>
{"name"=>"[FILTERED]", "favorite_color"=>"silver","likes_disco"
=>"false"}, "commit"=>"Update Profile", "id"=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention, that `filter_params_logging.rb` is inside `initializers` folder. Files inside `initializers` dir, as well as any config files, are not reloaded automatically. You need to restart your server, then `:name` will be filtered.

Comment: I restarted the server many times, still it is not reflecting